# PHP library to generate mysql table from data definition

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any existing PHP library to create or update a mysql table from a data definition? For example, Silverstripe can do it -- each model defines its data:

```
$db = array(
    'FieldName' => 'Boolean',
    'FieldName2' => 'Text',
);

$has_one = array(
    'RelationName' => 'ObjectType'
);
```

Which generates a table along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE classname (Id INT, FieldName BOOLEAN, FieldName2 TEXT, RelationNameId INT)
```

Or something. When you add columns to the db array, they're added to the database; if the new table would be incompatible with the old one, a new table is created and the old data imported into the new table. Pretty sure it handles all sorts of indices and things too.

Is there any standalone PHP library that does this? I don't want to use Silverstripe for this project.

My final goal is to be able to create a form in HTML, containing a table identifier and several input fields, and submit it to a controller which will create a table with data types for every piece of data which is submitted. If I add a field to the form, I want the controller to update the corresponding table.

Please don't suggest a way to code a CREATE TABLE statement from an array of data types -- this is only the start of what I need. I also need to be able to update existing tables by changing the array of data types in PHP -- this is a lot harder than simply creating a CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention Doctrine. Problem is that afaik Doctrine requires a specific kind of data definition which would be a bit hard to build on the fly -- and can you easily run the orm-schema-update command from within PHP, or would it need to be as a shell command? I suppose I could probably generate the simple YML required without too much effort... or can I use the schema definition tools directly?

Comment: you could write the script by yourself ... it is actually not that hard - use vsprintf($format, $data) where $data is an array (your $db-array) and $format your query

Comment: I addressed that in my question. Keeping it up to date is much, much more complicated than that.

Comment: Checked Propel? http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/10-migrations.html - it is not an array, but xml, but easy to map.

Comment: Propel doesn't look like it's got as much support for doing this inside PHP as Doctrine2 does. I'd have to create an XML file, call these shell commands, include the resultant PHP file, then run that migration class's code. Feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine2 looks like the way to go...

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html describes how to use the SchemaTool inside PHP, and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/php-mapping.html sets out how to create ClassMetadata objects for the SchemaTool to consume.

I would love to know how to do this by just creating Entities dynamically, adding them to the EntityManager, and creating the tables, but I don't think this is something that the Doctrine team had in mind, so I think I'd have to do a lot of it myself. So as a compromise, I've followed this approach: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/FRnvpHN7nFg/_JVDv61esfYJ

Sounds like the way to go is to create YML files dynamically (my data types are all simple so this isn't too hard), create the entites from the YML, then run the schema tool. However I'm going to have to come back to this -- going to create the databases the manual way for now for the good of the project.

Comment: Please update the answer with a bit more details when you figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is just a very light example of how I would do (of course it is very basic) but you may let the function save this to a .sql file or whatever. As I said I wouldn't use it as it is for now - so I did not recognize the performance etc.

```
<?php

define ('INTEGER', 'INT'); // may use constants etc.

function createTable($name, $fields)
{
    $format = 'CREATE TABLE %s (%s)';

    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $buffer[] = $field[0] . ' ' . $field[1];
    }

    $buffer = implode('; ', $buffer); // need to seperate list with a char different to comma
    $result = sprintf($format, $name, $buffer); // else it would be another argument for sprintf
    $result = str_replace(';', ',', $result); // replace the char with a comma

    print_r($result);
    return $result;
}

$name = 'mytable';
$data = array(
    array ('field 1', 'INT'),
    array ('field 2', 'VARCHAR (30)'),
    array ('foo', 'BAR'),
    array ('foo', INTEGER)
);

createTable($name, $data);

?>
```

Output: `CREATE TABLE mytable (field 1 INT, field 2 VARCHAR (30), foo BAR, foo INT)`

Comment: Thanks for the thought but this really isn't what I need -- this would only accomplish the first, easy step of creating the db. What if I want to update the table with a new field? This requires looking at the database schema, which is not something I want to hand code for a little project.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean with "update the table with a new field"? Adding a entirely new field (like alerting the table) or just updating some values?

Comment: Altering the table. So all of a sudden you need to be able to see what columns exist in the table, etc... I'm just about there with doctrine, will update my answer with my approach, which could definitely be improved.

Comment: Iam facing the same problem and dont find a good solution or library. Please post more about your experience.